# How to change network connection to DHCP, as default user without administrator password?

Tags: windows, batch, ethernet, dhcp, elevation

I manage many remote Windows 7 and Windows 10 PCs that are logged on as standard users, where I log on to these via remote control program for necessary maintenance. The PCs are set up with a static IP address, and the users do not have access to the administrator password.
Sometimes I lose contact with some of the PCs, and to restore the connection, the network connection on the PC has to be changed to DHCP.
Is there a method where users can change this, without having to enter the administrator password, e.g. by running a script that changes the network connection to DHCP, or by giving the default user administrator permission for the required functions?
I have searched this site, and found partial answers, and have tried a script that changes to DHCP, but where the password is provided.
This is a part of the script that do the job:
netsh interface ip set address "Ethernet" source=dhcp
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Ethernet" source=dhcp
netsh interface ip show config "Ethernet".

Comment: You cannot;  The simplest solution is to use DHCP and assigned same IP address to the desired device.

Comment: To expand on the comment from @Ramhound you need to implement DHCP reserved addresses. Each desktop will always be using DHCP to assign addresses but you control the address assignments based on MAC addresses.